# Powershell Selecting NoteProperty Type Objects From Object

Tags: powershell, pscustomobject

I am working with deeply nested JSON and, after convertfrom-json, need to be able to traverse through various parts of the object which the convertfrom-json cmdlet generates.

I have no way of knowing in advance what property names may or may not be inside the object, as far as I can tell, there are hundreds of different possible properties. Fortunately the one thing I am seeing that helps is that each of the properties I care about is of type "NoteProperty".

Here is an example:

```
TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name               MemberType   Definition
----               ----------   ----------
Equals             Method       bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode        Method       int GetHashCode()
GetType            Method       type GetType()
ToString           Method       string ToString()
definition         NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject definition=@{$schema=https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsof... 
integrationAccount NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject integrationAccount=@{id=[parameters('integrationAccounts_xxx_integration... 
parameters         NoteProperty System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject parameters=@{$connections=}
state              NoteProperty string state=Enabled
```

So I thought it would be simple to create a function which would select only the objects, for the level currently being processed, which are of 'MemberType' 'NoteProperty'.

I have tried piping the object to:

```
where-object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" }
```

Nope.

I have tried select-object in various forms too but can't seem to select just what I need. I found an old article from the Scripting guys about using Labels and Expressions - but that seems like overkill, no? Can someone point me to simple way to select just the NoteProperty items?

Thanks!

Comment: take a look at the hidden `.PSObject` property of most powershell objects. it contains a property named `.Properties` that will give you all the props for the object ... and you can iterate thru them. if you need to dig into sub-properties, then you may find it easier to use regex on the raw JSON ... [*sigh ...*]

Comment: Another approach would be to use Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty to get the property names.  I think PSObject.Properties makes more sense, though.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey
Thank you so much! Yes, that is a great solution and thanks to your suggestion I am up and running again. Thank you!

Comment: @Indrid - kool! glad to have helped a little bit ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the hidden `.psobject.properties` to iterate over the members.

```
$json = @'
{
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "firstName": "Krish",
      "lastName": "Lee",
      "phoneNumber": "123456",
      "emailAddress": "krish.lee@learningcontainer.com"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "firstName": "racks",
      "lastName": "jacson",
      "phoneNumber": "123456",
      "emailAddress": "racks.jacson@learningcontainer.com"
    }
  ]
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$json | foreach {
    $_.psobject.properties | foreach {
        Write-Host Property Name: $_.name
        Write-Host Values: $_.value
    }
}
```

You can keep going as needed.

```
$json | foreach {
    $_.psobject.properties | foreach {
        $_.value | foreach {
            $_.psobject.properties | foreach {
                write-host Property name: $_.name
                write-host Property value: $_.value
            }
        }
    }
}

Property name: userId
Property value: 1
Property name: firstName
Property value: Krish
Property name: lastName
Property value: Lee
Property name: phoneNumber
Property value: 123456
Property name: emailAddress
Property value: krish.lee@learningcontainer.com
Property name: userId
Property value: 2
Property name: firstName
Property value: racks
Property name: lastName
Property value: jacson
Property name: phoneNumber
Property value: 123456
Property name: emailAddress
Property value: racks.jacson@learningcontainer.com
```

Comment: Yes! This technique works out really well for me... some work to do to filter down on the output as I am recursively checking to see if the current $val is a PSCustomObject and it it is I am sending it through the function again to unpack everything in there... so a little messy - but it works! Thanks!

Comment: The `.PSObject` is an intrinsic member and is documented here: [about_intrinsic_members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_intrinsic_members?view=powershell-7.3)

Answer (score 4):

To complement [Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64187726/45375) with a *generalized* solution:

The following snippet defines and calls **function `Get-LeafProperty`, which recursively walks an object graph** - such as returned by [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) - and **outputs all *leaf* property values, along with their *name paths* in the hierarchy**.

```
# Define a walker function for object graphs:
# Get all leaf properties in a given object's hierarchy,
# namely properties of primitive and quasi-primitive types 
# (.NET primitive types, plus those that serialize to JSON as a single value).
# Output:
#  A flat collection of [pscustomobject] instances with .NamePath and .Value 
#  properties; e.g.:
#   [pscustomobject] @{ NamePath = 'results.users[0].userId'; Value = 1 }
function Get-LeafProperty {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [object] $InputObject, [string] $NamePath)
  process {   
    if ($null -eq $InputObject -or $InputObject -is [DbNull] -or $InputObject.GetType().IsPrimitive -or $InputObject.GetType() -in [string], [datetime], [datetimeoffset], [decimal], [bigint]) {
      # A null-like value or a primitive / quasi-primitive type -> output.
      # Note: Returning a 2-element ValueTuple would result in better performance, both time- and space-wise:
      #      [ValueTuple]::Create($NamePath, $InputObject)
      [pscustomobject] @{ NamePath = $NamePath; Value = $InputObject }
    }
    elseif ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IEnumerable] -and $InputObject -isnot [System.Collections.IDictionary]) {
      # A collection of sorts (other than a string or dictionary (hash table)), 
      # recurse on its elements.
      $i = 0
      foreach ($o in $InputObject) { Get-LeafProperty $o ($NamePath + '[' + $i++ + ']') }
    }
    else { 
      # A non-quasi-primitive scalar object or a dictionary:
      # enumerate its properties / entries.
      $props = if ($InputObject -is [System.Collections.IDictionary]) { $InputObject.GetEnumerator() } else { $InputObject.psobject.properties }
      $sep = '.' * ($NamePath -ne '')
      foreach ($p in $props) {
        Get-LeafProperty $p.Value ($NamePath + $sep + $p.Name)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example use:

```
# Parse sample JSON with multiple hierarchy levels into a [pscustomobject]
# graph using ConvertFrom-Json.
$objectGraphFromJson = @'
{
  "results": {
      "users": [
          {
              "userId": 1,
              "emailAddress": "jane.doe@example.com",
              "attributes": {
                  "height": 165,
                  "weight": 60
              }
          },
          {
              "userId": 2,
              "emailAddress": "john.doe@example.com",
              "attributes": {
                  "height": 180,
                  "weight": 72
              }
          }
      ]
  }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

# Get all leaf properties.
Get-LeafProperty $objectGraphFromJson
```

The above yields:

```
NamePath                                          Value
--------                                          -----
results.users[0].userId                               1
results.users[0].emailAddress      jane.doe@example.com
results.users[0].attributes.height                  165
results.users[0].attributes.weight                   60
results.users[1].userId                               2
results.users[1].emailAddress      john.doe@example.com
results.users[1].attributes.height                  180
results.users[1].attributes.weight                   72
```

Comment: I use your code to compare 2 json files and merge the result.
Is there a way to convert this back to a json?
Ofc with the original structure.  (ConvertTo-Json) alone will not do.

Comment: That's an interesting use case, @njefsky, and I encourage you to ask a _new_ question focused on that. One conceptual problem that comes to mind is: say you have a result with path `results.users[4].attributes.weight`, but not also for array indices `0` through `3`, how would you handle that?

Comment: I have the merge part covered, in your example I make sure the order and number of the users are the same.
The thing I do not seem able to solve is how to translate the path back to a json again.

Comment: @njefsky, I see. As stated, I suggest you ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this is to get your results into some select expressions and then sort on that.

In yours, you have integrationAccount and parameters as note properties, so if these were in a pscustomobject called $results

```
$results = $results | Select @{l="integrationAccount ";e={$_.integrationAccount }},@{l="parameters ";e={$_.parameters }}
```

Then you'll be able to do a Select and/or Where-Object on that.