# PowerShell iterate through json of key value pairs

Tags: json, powershell, reflection

I have a json file that maps alpha-2 codes to country names:

```
{
    "AF": "Afghanistan",
    "EG": "Ägypten",
    ...
}
```

I want to iterate over each key value pair to process the data. How would I be able to achieve that?

I tried the following but it always returns one big object that is not iterable in a key value manner:

```
$json = Get-Content -Path C:\countries.json | ConvertFrom-Json
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I was able to achieve it like this, using the [intrinsic `.psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#object-views):

```
foreach ($obj in $json.PSObject.Properties) {
    $obj.Name
    $obj.Value
}
```

Comment: Nice; for someone looking to extract the name paths and values of all leaf properties in an arbitrarily _nested_ JSON object, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189034/45375).