# Powershell getting nested values: Can you use ConvertFrom-Json for nested Values

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, properties, psobject

I have a json file, simplified version of it looks like this:

```
 {
  "Location": "EU",
  "Country": {
    "City": "xxx",
    "Town": "xxx"
  },
  "Transport": {
    "Train": "xxx"
  }
}
```

I have run the ConvertFrom-Json command to convert to PSObject:

```
$conversion = Get-Content $path | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This will give me an output like this:

```
Location                           : EU
Country                            : @{City="xxx"; Town="xxx"}
Transport                          : @{Train="xxx"}
```

**Question**

How can I get the nested values to print out separately? I would want them all to print out like the "Location:EU" one

Is there a different command to ConvertFrom-Json that i should be using for this? Or do I just need to mess around with ConvertFrom-Json command a bit?

To note:

- I am not just looking for a pretty print out - I would need them all separately for a script I am writing that will be looping through all the key/value pairs
- I have read about the -Depth flag when using ConvertFrom-Json and does not seem to fix anything here - it seemed this was more relevant for ConvertTo-Json

Comment: I think the way you have it will work fine, that output is just how powershell displays the nesting.  For example if you do `$conversion.Country.City` you will just get `xxx` out.

Comment: @frankM_DN thanks for replying! strange - that doesn't work for me. It returns nothing

Comment: hmm. I just copied the text that you say is in the json file into a string variable and it worked for me.  So maybe something wonky with the json file?  I put that text into a file and used `get-content | convertfrom-json` and that worked as well.

Answer (score 2):

In order **to report all *leaf* properties as *name-value pairs*** (i.e. those properties that contain primitive JSON values as opposed to containing nested objects with properties and / or arrays), you need to **recursively walk** the object graph:

Find helper function `Get-LeafProperty` below; assuming you have already defined it, you can call it as follows:

```bash
@'
  {
    "Location": "EU",
    "Country": {
      "City": "xxx",
      "Town": "xxy"
    },
    "Transport": {
      "Train": "xxz"
    }
  }
'@ | 
  ConvertFrom-Json |
  Get-LeafProperty
```

Output (the display formatting of `[pscustomobject]` instances with `.Name` and `.Value` properties representing all the leaf properties):

```bash
Name     Value
----     -----
Location EU
City     xxx
Town     xxy
Train    xxz
```

---

**`Get-LeafProperty` source code**:

```bash
# Walks a potentially nested [pscustomobject] graph
# as returned by ConvertFrom-Json and outputs all
# leaf properties as name-value custom objects.
function Get-LeafProperty {
  param([Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)] [object] $InputObject)
  process {   
    if ($InputObject -is [array]) { # array as single input object -> recurse
      foreach ($o in $InputObject) { Get-LeafProperty $o }
    }
    else { 
      # Assumed to be a (potentially nested) [pscustomobject] instance:
      # Recursively process its properties.
      foreach ($p in $InputObject.psobject.properties) {
        if ($p.Value -is [array]) { # array -> recurse
          foreach ($o in $p.Value) { Get-LeafProperty $o }
        } elseif ($p.Value -is [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] ) { # nested [pscustomobject] -> recurse
          Get-LeafProperty $p.Value
        } else { # leaf property reached -> output name-value pair
          [pscustomobject] @{ Name = $p.Name; Value = $p.Value }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note: A *variant* of this function that outputs property name *paths*  (e.g. `Country.City`) instead of just their *names* (e.g. `City`) can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64189034/45375).